# Как при клике добавить переменную в массив, а при повторном клике ее удалить на JQUERY

Tags: jquery, массивы

На сайте есть блок список товаров (в моем случае это мобильные номера) - номера в виде кнопок. Необходимо, чтобы посетитель сайта мог кликнуть на понравившейся номер (или несколько номеров) из списка (список 50 номеров), номер выделился цветом и добавился в форму сайта в строчку "выбранные номера". Если по номеру кликает повторно - этот номер удаляется.

Сейчас код такой (не могу понять как сделать, чтобы номер удалялся):

JQUERY:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
 $(function() {
  $('.btn_1').click(function() {
     $(this).toggleClass('click_number_green');
  });
 });

var items = [];
$('.btn_1').on('click', function() {
  var value = $(this).data('pos');
  if(items.indexOf(value)==-1){
   items.push(value);
  }
  $('#out').text(items);
 });
});
```

```html
<div id="btn">
<p><button class="btn_1" data-pos="925-764-85-63">925-764-85-63</button></p>
<p><button class="btn_1" data-pos="925-645-85-73">925-645-85-73</button></p>
<p><button class="btn_1" data-pos="925-111-35-67">925-111-35-67</button></p>
<p><button class="btn_1" data-pos="925-722-12-34">925-722-12-34</button></p>
<p><button class="btn_1" data-pos="925-764-85-63">925-764-85-63</button></p>
<p><button class="btn_1" data-pos="925-764-85-63">925-764-85-63</button></p>
<p><button class="btn_1" data-pos="925-764-85-63">925-764-85-63</button></p>
<p><button class="btn_1" data-pos="925-764-85-63">925-764-85-63</button></p>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

На сонную голову пришёл такой вариант:

```js
$('.number').on('click', function(){
  let numberArr = []; // создаём пустой массив
  $(this).toggleClass('selected'); // вешаем класс
  $('.number.selected').each(function(){ // проходим по всем элементам с классом
    numberArr.push($(this).text()); // добавляем их текст в массив
  });
  // Ниже лог, можно удалить
  console.clear();
  console.info('Выбраные номера: '+numberArr);
});
```

```css
.number {display: inline-block; padding: 3px; margin-bottom: 3px; cursor: pointer;}
.number:last-child {margin-bottom: 0;}
.number:hover {background: #ddd;}
.number.selected {background: blue; color: #fff;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="number">8-123-123-00-00</div>
<div class="number">8-123-123-11-11</div>
<div class="number">8-123-123-22-22</div>
<div class="number">8-123-123-33-33</div>
<div class="number">8-123-123-44-44</div>
<div class="number">8-123-123-55-55</div>
<div class="number">8-123-123-66-66</div>
<div class="number">8-123-123-77-77</div>
<div class="number">8-123-123-88-88</div>
<div class="number">8-123-123-99-99</div>
```

**Из плюсов**: Сохраняется порядок номеров по DOM.
**Из минусов**: При большом кол-во элементов (что на странице, что в массиве) будет долго обрабатываться.

Comment: Спасибо, все работает!

Answer (score 1):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(function() {
    $('.btn_1').click(function() {
      $(this).toggleClass('click_number_green');
    });
  });

  var items = [];
  $('.btn_1').on('click', function() {
    var value = $(this).data('pos');
    (items.indexOf(value) == -1)? items.push(value) : items.splice(index, 1);
    $('#out').text(items);
  });
});
```

```css
.click_number_green {
  background: lightgreen;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="out"></div>
<div id="btn">
  <p><button class="btn_1" data-pos="925-764-85-63">925-764-85-63</button></p>
  <p><button class="btn_1" data-pos="925-645-85-73">925-645-85-73</button></p>
  <p><button class="btn_1" data-pos="925-111-35-67">925-111-35-67</button></p>
  <p><button class="btn_1" data-pos="925-722-12-34">925-722-12-34</button></p>
  <p><button class="btn_1" data-pos="925-764-85-63">925-764-85-63</button></p>
  <p><button class="btn_1" data-pos="925-764-85-63">925-764-85-63</button></p>
  <p><button class="btn_1" data-pos="925-764-85-63">925-764-85-63</button></p>
  <p><button class="btn_1" data-pos="925-764-85-63">925-764-85-63</button></p>

</div>
```